# Scipy - area between two curves

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-methods

I have an input signal that my system is supposed to follow. This signal changes every 4 seconds. I take measurements of the output as fast as the system allows.

Here is an input schedule (shortened):

```
input_data = 

[['0', '0'],['4','0'],
 ['4', '-0.075408269'],
 ['8','-.075408269'],
 ['8', '-0.075133293'],
 ['12','-0.075133293'],
 ['12', '-0.075228368']...
```

And some output data (shortened):

```
output_data = 

 [['0.0', '-1.92884041347e-05'],
 ['0.385990779068', '-1.92884041347e-05'],
 ['0.652384253241', '-3.20466635861e-05'],
 ['0.917284728537', '-1.92868566406e-05'],
 ['1.18289737777', '-3.20440903147e-05'],
 ['1.4479258519', '-1.92837604576e-05'],
 ['1.71312114154', '-1.92837604576e-05'],
 ['1.97829750404', '-3.20389477431e-05'],
 ['2.24393068441', '-3.20389477431e-05'],
 ['2.50852094701', '-3.20363764573e-05'],
 ['2.77392571844', '-1.92806654695e-05'],
 ['3.03912132888', '-1.92806654695e-05'],
 ['3.30450492758', '-1.92791167805e-05'],
 ['3.56940123249', '-3.20312319002e-05'],
 ['3.83460582531', '-3.20312319002e-05'],
 ['4.10000450158', '-3.20312319002e-05'],
 ['4.36509456911', '-0.0753899203822'],
 ['4.63028600917', '-0.0754154062438'],
 ['4.8955233235', '-0.075402663313'],
 ['5.16063488457', '-0.0754220898514'],
 ['5.42586289573', '-0.0754093479443'],
 ['5.69089489864', '-0.0754032896447'],
 ['5.95638981462', '-0.0754032896447'],
 ['6.22145485983', '-0.075397226667'],
 ['6.48666073585', '-0.0754160305282'],
 ['6.75187270704', '-0.0754160305282'],
 ['7.01701827283', '-0.075397226667'],
 ['7.28112027923', '-0.075397226667'],
 ['7.53174038384', '-0.0754099665259'],
 ['7.79702613882', '-0.0754166531947'],
 ['8.06223426043', '-0.0754105928472'],
 ['8.32742056769', '-0.0751303252107'],
 ['8.59244647543', '-0.0751363630346'],
 ['8.85782750774', '-0.0751303252107'],
 ['9.12303113815', '-0.0751370195117'],
 ['9.38824727973', '-0.0751309806642'],
 ['9.65310573036', '-0.0751309806642'],
 ['9.91784195654', '-0.0751309806642'],
 ['10.1839925858', '-0.0751242827245'],
 ['10.4489851304', '-0.0751437164277'],
 ['10.7132407996', '-0.0751249418166'],
 ['10.9636126057', '-0.0751249418166'],
 ['11.2291107297', '-0.0751376765565'],
 ['11.4941857197', '-0.0751376765565'],
 ['11.7594365076', '-0.0751249418166'],
 ['12.0243972931', '-0.0751316320213']...
```

A plot of the two (shortened) sets are shown below.
[image: Input Vs Output]

How could I go about calculating the total area between the two curves?

Comment: Why is this tagged with matlab?

Comment: This is pure math I think

Comment: I think you make a few assumptions with your data. Like that the value for `x=0` continues until `x=4` for input. That's not guaranteed, and linear interpolation could be a valueable candidate as well.

Comment: sorry, edited it to correct the dataset. I tagged it with Matlab because I figured that people who work with MatLab frequently would have come across this problem before...

Comment: You might want to start by converting your data to floating point numpy arrays rather than nested lists of strings...

Comment: @DannyD people who know scipy probably follow *that* tag. And if your question does not apply to any specific programming language, than odds are you're off-topic:)

Comment: How should we interpret the two "columns" of `input_data` and `output_data`? Do they correspond to x and y coordinates respectively?

Comment: I've removed the matlab tag, because your not using matlab. Is this a math problem in disguise or a programming question?

Comment: Just to answer only a bit: if you define how your underlying functions should be understood (linear interpolator? piecewise linear? spline? (hope not)), then you can first compute interpolating functions for the two curves, then define a function from the difference of the two interpolators (possibly by using a `lambda`), then integrate that function numerically (after having computed some reasonable limit points, but you don't have to be too precise as your function will be roughly 0 outside a finite support).

Comment: If you're serious about those linear functions in the plot (don't be!), you can just determine the 2x2 break points (from looking at the `diff`, perhaps) and compute the area of the corresponding trapezoid.

Comment: Thanks for the input. @ali_m that's right.

Comment: DannyD, don't you mean that both `input_data` and `output_data` contain `[x,y]` pairs each? At least I think @ali_m asked the opposite. It should be *almost* clear, but only because the `x` data are non-negative... (Anyway: ali_m should be writing their thesis!)

Comment: Thanks @AndrasDeak. Defining the functions is very difficult. I have an input signal that my system is supposed to follow. This signal changes every 4 seconds. I take measurements of the output as fast as the system allows.

Comment: @AndrasDeak What I meant was: if `a = np.array(input_data, np.float32)` then would `a[:, 0]` be the set of x coordinates and `a[:, 1]` be the corresponding y-coordinates for one of the two "curves"? (you are correct about the thesis... I will let you field this one)

Comment: DannyD, frankly I still don't think that's a programming question. You have to model your system first, if you want to describe it in any meaningful quantitative way. If you have a model, then the algorithm will be straightforward. Also (frankly), 1/3 seconds of sampling seems quite rare for a step-like response, if you want to integrate the difference. Most of your integrated signal will be an artifact.

Comment: @ali_m ah, OK then, sorry. I misunderstood your "`respectively`":) And I don't think we'll end up with an actual answer here, anyway.

Comment: take cumulative sum of both functions and substract them